# Getting server response code in oracle jet web service call

Tags: rest, oracle-jet

I am calling a REST Webservice from Oracle jet ViewModel. The server response as I expected, but how to catch the server response (If the server response is like 400,422). I tried with the following lines of code, but it doesn't seem to be working.

```
               self.User = oj.Model.extend({
                    urlRoot : self.resourceUrl,
                    idAttribute : "userId"
                });

                var user = new self.User();
                user.save( 
                        {
                          success: function(user, response, options) {
                          console.log("response "+response);
                          },
                          error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                            console.log("error thrwos "+errorThrown);
                            console.log("status "+textStatus);
                      }
                  });
```

All I want to do is, if server response is a success, show the user a success message and navigate to the next page and if the response is an error( 400 or 422 or whatever), show the user an error message ( this can be done using a validator).

Comment: I hope you already consulted the docs: https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/jet320/jet/reference-jet/oj.Model.html#save
  Also what's not working? What is (not) happening?

Comment: Yes, I consulted the docs and some blogs but nowhere I could find a scenario how the server response has been processed for a  POST request. Basically, when the server responds back with a 422 error, I should be able to catch the response in the Jet VM and print that in the console. This is what not working.  When I  save() using ojMode.save(), I am able to save the data at the server end, but not able to monitor it. That is,  at the client end, no clue if the server responded successfully or not.

Comment: The `oj.Model.save()` has two arguments, and what you try to set belongs to the second. Try calling it as `user.save({}, {/*your object*/})`.

Comment: @Koshinae  It worked.  The issue was I had completely ignored the first argument ( thinking its optional). When I  provided an empty object as the argument and used the callbacks as the second argument, it worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the JSDocs for model.save  http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/jet/jsdocs/oj.Model.html#save

You will see that you can define a callback function to handled the error returned by the save call.

This would work with what @Koshinae is saying in his comment above about options.